# CodingBat - Warmup2 - ARRAY_FRONT9

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new to programming and I'd like your expertise on a problem I've come across on CodingBat.
But I am not sure why my solution doesn't work. What am I missing here?

**THE PROBLEM**

Given an array of ints, return True if one of the first 4 elements in the array is a 9. The array length may be less than 4.

array_front9([1, 2, 9, 3, 4]) → True 
array_front9([1, 2, 3, 4, 9]) → False 
array_front9([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) → False

**MY SOLUTION**

```
def array_front9(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        if len(nums)> 0 and nums[i] == 9:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**SOLUTION ONLINE**

```
def array_front9(nums):
  # First figure the end for the loop
  end = len(nums)
    if end > 4:
    end = 4

    for i in range(end):  # loop over index [0, 1, 2, 3]
        if nums[i] == 9:
            return True
        return False
```

Your assistance is appreciated. Thank you all.

[Screenshot with the expected answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTNB6.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is exiting prematurely with its `return False` line. As it's currently written, the code says, "Check the first number in the list. If it's a 9, *end the function* and return `True`. Otherwise, *end the function* and return `False`." That's what `return` statements do: *end the function* and (optionally) return something.

All you need to do to fix this is remove the `else` block and change the indentation of `return False`:

```
def array_front9(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 9:
            return True
    return False
```

(Your extra check for `len(nums) > 0` is unnecessary since `range(0, 0)` will simply do nothing and the `for` loop will be skipped.)

By unindenting `return False`, that line will now run only after the `for` loop has completed, which is what you want. Note you'll still need to modify this code to check only the first 4 items in the array.

Also, outside of a learning context like CodingBat, in the real world Python does all of this work for you. You can just write `9 in nums[:4]` and get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER UPDATE**

Thanks to user JDAZ, I've come up with a working solution. Hoping this can shed some light towards beginners.

SOLUTION:

```
def array_front9(nums):
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 9 and i < 4:
            return True
    return False
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always return `False`.

In your code, you create an empty list `mylist` and don't put anything in it.  Length of such list is always `0`.  So, the condition in your `if` loop will never be true.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've modified it so that it doesn't account for the empty list. But I've noticed that it ONLY shows true if i execute array_front9 ([9])..

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
def array_front9(nums):
  for i in nums[0:3]:
    if i == 9:
      return True
  return False
```

[image]